# Implement a node transformer in arpeggio

Tags: python, parsing, dsl, peg

I'm trying to implement a Node Transformer class in the Arpeggio PEG parser. However there's no support to copy nodes for modification (deep copy doesn't work on nodes for instance). The main goal is to implement preprocessing and syntactic sugar in a small programming language.

Any hints on how to do this are welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic approach to implement tree transformations in Arpeggio is by using [visitors](http://www.igordejanovic.net/Arpeggio/semantics/).

> In Arpeggio a visitor pattern is used for semantic analysis. You write a python class that inherits PTNodeVisitor and has a methods of the form visit_(self, node, children) where rule name is a rule name from the grammar.
>
> During a semantic analysis a parse tree is walked in the depth-first manner and for each node a proper visitor method is called to transform it to some other form. The results are than fed to the parent node visitor method. This is repeated until the final, top level parse tree node is processed (its visitor is called). The result of the top level node is the final output of the semantic analysis.

Edit: Do not edit PT nodes. Create your objects instead. This will require you to design your language AST model (meta-model) first and than instantiate elements of this model during tree node visiting.

For a complex transformations of parse trees you can investigate [textX source code](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/blob/master/textx/textx.py).

If you are developing a small language I highly recommend you to take a closer look at [textX](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX). It is much easier to use in comparison to classical parsing technologies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to implement some syntactic sugar cases and the best way to do it is either by rewriting the code or altering the parse tree. Basically I'm looking for something like python's [NodeTransformer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer)

Comment: which is a visitor pattern using  utilities to copy and easily modified nodes.I agree that textX is a better tool but I'm looking for portability in terms of the language definition.

Comment: @DemianWassermann I don't see any reason why Arpeggio`s `ParseTreeNode` won't be able to support deep copy. Please register this in Arpeggio's issue tracker. Furthermore, node transformation support could be done similarly to visitors. This can be also registered in issue tracker as a new feature request.

Comment: I think the main issue comes from the reimplementation of `getattr` at some point it should default to `super`'s getattr if not that can generate different inconsistencies with python's standard API, e.g. deep copy. I'll try to submit a pull request for ParseTreeNode and it's subclasses if this is OK with you.

Comment: OK, the problem runs deeper than I thought. I will submit an issue. Thanks